# .NET Core 2.2 Plugin Framework and Assembly Redirection

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly, versioning

I've written an application in .Net Core 2.2 that is extensible with plugins.  A plugin is a DLL that has an implementation of my plugin base class.  The plugin base class is defined in a shared dll.

I have updated the dll that has the base class with some non-breaking changes.  I have now updated my application to use the new version of the shared dll.  Now when I try to load a plugin I wrote using the old version of the shared DLL I get an error.  If I don't rev the version of my shared DLL the plugin loads fine.

Here is the code I'm using to scan and load my plugin:

```
        foreach (var dll in Directory.GetFiles("baseDir", "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            _logger.Info("Loading {0}", dll);
            var a = Assembly.LoadFile(dll);
            availableAssemblies[a.GetName().Name] = a;
        }

        // setup assembly resolver with scanned assemblies
        AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Resolving += (_, b) =>
        {
            if (availableAssemblies.ContainsKey(b.Name))
                return availableAssemblies[b.Name];

            _logger.Info("Can't file assembly {0}", b.Name);
            return null;
        };


        foreach (var a in availableAssemblies)
        {
            _logger.Info("Searching {0} for plugin", a.Value.FullName);
            plugin = Array.Find(a.Value.GetTypes(), t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && GetAllBaseClasses(t).Any(b => b.FullName == typeof(PluginBase).FullName));
        }
```

How can I make my application 'redirect' the shared assembly used by my plugin to the one it has loaded?

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483550/replacing-dll-to-a-newer-version

Comment: I don't think that will work in .NET Core

Comment: @Zeus82  I'm stuck in a similar situation. You found any solution for this?

Comment: No... still nothing...